# Cocoapods dependency manager increase the size of xcode project or not?

Tags: ios

1. I am little confused whether cocoa pods  increase the size of our project or not. Although there is other many benefits of using cocoa pods.
2. I have search but they only said it will increase  size only when you copy the repo.What happens  if i will not increase the repo

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods keeps the external library files separate from your own source code.

If you mean “project” to be the actual `.xcodeproj` file and files it references, then no. It will not add to that size. (Other than changing some configuration options)

If you mean “project” to be all files associated with your app, then yes. Any package manager will do that because it’s downloading external files.

However, you can choose to not put CocoaPods’ files in source control (e.g. Git).

You can do one of two things:

1. Put all files into source control. This increases the size of your repo, but no one else needs to run `pod install`.
2. Put only the `Podfile.lock` into source control. This will make your repo smaller, but every time you clone the repo, you must have CocoaPods installed and run `pod install`.